# Parsing Serial Data over TCP/IP from WIZ110SR in python

Tags: python, sockets, serial-port

I'm currently setting up my new weather station with an RS232-connector and want to parse its data from an WIZ110SR Serial-to-TCP/IP converter using python.

I've already connected it up directly via a Serial-USB adapter, which works flawlessly using this code:

```
def read_serial():
    serialport.flushInput()
    serialport.flushOutput()
    while True: 
        data = serialport.readline()
        try:
            data = data.decode("utf-8").strip()
            print(data)
        except:
            print("This string does not comply with the UTF-8 standard")
```

This is the code i've gotten so far using socks to gather the raw serial data from the WIZ110SR

```
def read_serial():
    dstrng = ""
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024) 
        dstrng += data.decode("utf-8")
        try:
            dstrng = dstrng.rstrip()
            dstrng = dstrng.strip()
            print(dstrng)
        except:
            print("This string does not comply with the UTF-8 standard")
```

Using the socks variant, it seems, that the raw data can only be read char by char

Comment: Your rs232 version uses readline to ensure a complete line has been received, whereas your tcp/ip version doesn’t - you should accumulate data from the socket until you have a line, reserving anything beyond that \n for the next accumulation, so nothing is thrown away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't had chance to test this, but you can try using socket.makefile() to give your socket a file-like quality so that readline works, like this:

after creating the socket:

```
    f = s.makefile() # do this once
```

then to get data:

```
    while True:
        data = f.readline()
        try:
            data = data.decode("utf-8").strip()
            print(data)
        except:
            print("This string does not comply with the UTF-8 standard")
```

although if your socket is non-blocking (has a timeout) this might not work. YMMV so try it.